# Getting previous element of given in dom model

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of elements on my page

```
input
input
span
input
span
etc
```

I want to select each input that sits before each span, and after do, whatever i will have to. Is there any available ways to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `prev()` to select the previous input of any given span:

```
$(this).prev("input");
```

---

If you're trying to select all previous inputs of all spans in 1 selector try this:

```
​$("span").prev("input");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hPRa/1/

```
$("span").prev("input").css("background-color", "pink");​
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i needed. But is there any simple way to do this to each of spans in my DOM?

Comment: `$("span").prev("input")` should select all `span` elements on the DOM and then select all of their previous `input` elements

Answer (score 5):

You have to use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

ex :

```
$('span').prev("input")  //this is input element
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .parent() or .parents('.selector').first()

```
jQuery('.given').parent();
```

OR without jQuery

```
var el = document.getElementById('id');
el.parentNode...
```

AHH, previous-element...
Ok, now you have an answer.
Further there is a method

```
.siblings()
```

If you want the prev-prev element do so

```
jQuery('.given').prev().prev();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy to define which one should be the first, I suggest go with set tabindex for each of them, and then with that using that as a selector you can always easily grab the previous one or next one